# How to programmatically get the current database Mongoid is writing to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-ruby, mongoid3

I am talking to multiple databases using Mongoid.override_database("database_name") using Mongoid with rails. How do I find the current database programmatically?

Mongoid docs on sessions: http://mongoid.org/en/moped/docs/driver.html define methods to override database but do not define a way to get the current database in use.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Got it!

```
Mongoid.default_session.options[:database]
```

Comment: It's now by symbol: `Mongoid.default_session.options[:database]`

Comment: Warning, this is NOT thread safe!! - if you are switching databases in a before_filter in your application controller, this returns the database name used in other threads in the application.

Comment: This seems to be deprecated.

Comment: It is now `Mongoid.default_client.options[:database]`

Answer (score 8):

The new way to get this is

```
Mongoid::Config.clients["default"]["database"]
```

You can also just have a look at

```
Mongoid::Config.clients
```

to see what else is available.

Comment: You can use symbols as well. `Mongoid::Config.clients[:default][:database]`

Answer (score 4):

If you want the overrided database you actually need to use

```
Mongoid::Threaded.database_override
```

Answer (score 4):

Mongoid Version 7.0.5

```
Mongoid.client(:default).database
```

Answer (score 2):

Running Mongoid.default_session.options[:database] gives an error that default_session is invalid.  It is now default_client. That works wonderfully.

Run it without the [:database] to get all the option and see the full configuration of your database.

Mongoid::Config.clients["default"]["database"] assumes you are **NOT** using the uri version of mongoid.yml. You will get nil in all cases.  Use Mongoid::Config.clients["default"] to get the full configuration of the current database, or  Mongoid::Config.clients["default"]['uri'] to give you just the full uri.

Pick the database name from the URI after the last port number/.  There could be severalif using a sharded configuration